# azure web app where is fopen('test.csv') saved?

Tags: php, azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service, fopen

The file test.csv is created in my laravel root dir when I execute

```
$file = fopen('test.csv');
```

locally.

However I cannot find the file when accessing the azure webapp over ftp.

Where would it be saved to?

Comment: It would be saved to the current working directory. Which is something you should never rely on. Always use absolute paths, or at very least, relative to the same directory where the executed file lies (using `__DIR__` for example).

Answer (score 0):

You should specify absolute path for this.

`fopen('test.csv')` will create the file in the root directory which may be variable based on azure infrastructure stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Your php code seems to be incorrect which lack a parameter `mode` in the function [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php). There are four PHP versions supported for WebApps on Azure portal, which include `5.6`, `7.0`, `7.1` and `7.2`, as below.

[image]

I tried to execute `fopen('test.csv')` by using each PHP version on Kudu console to get the same error `PHP Warning:  fopen() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in Command line code on line 1`.

[image]

Except using `fopen('test.csv', 'w')`, it will create a `test.csv` file in my current directory of Kudu console.

[image]

So I guess some configuration or code in your laravel project cover this error up.

Meanwhile, as @Marzouk said, using a specify absoulte path for the `fopen` parameter `$filename` will be helpful to avoid uncertain file path created.